# Giving wrong some value though logic is correct check for many times

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve this HackerRank problem:

- https://hackerrank.com/challenges/electronics-shop/problem.

Test for this input: the first line contains three space-separated integers: b, n and m — the budget, the number of keyboard models, and the number of USB drive models.
The second line contains n space-separated integers `keyboard[i]`, the prices of each keyboard model.
The third line contains m space-separated integers `drives[i]`, the prices of the USB drive.

**INPUT:**

10 2 3

3 1

5 2 8

and it's returning output 8 instead of 9 which is under budget 10.

```
 int getMoneySpent(int keyboards_count, int* keyboards, int drives_count, int* drives, int b) {
    int i,j,set_max=0,current=-1;
    for(j=0;j<=drives_count;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<=keyboards_count;i++)
        {
        
            if(drives[j]+keyboards[i]>=set_max)
            {
               set_max=drives[j]+keyboards[i];
              if(set_max<=b)
              {
                current=set_max;
              }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return current;
}
```

Comment: Side note: This approach is brute force and brute force solutions rarely pass competition requirements because they're too slow. Are you sure you're getting a wrong answer and not a time limit exceeded?

Comment: Worth stepping through the function with the debugger that came with your development tools and see where the program violates your expectation by taking the wrong path or storing an incorrect value. That'll be a bug, and since you know what the program should have done and what it did, usually you can see what changes you need to make to your program. If not, craft a [mre] and see if that helps. If you're still stuck, add the MRE to the question..

Comment: You do have editorial section on hackerrank. you can always refer that section to check whether what you are doing is correct or not. Moreover always dry run your code to see whether you are implementing your logic correctly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this works. Your implementation of logic was a bit wrong. You need to check the sum if it's greater than your current sum , not the set_max  to get the maximum sum as output.

```
int getMoneySpent(int keyboards_count, int* keyboards, int drives_count, int* drives, int b) {
    int i,j,set_max=0,current=-1;
    for(j=0;j<drives_count;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<keyboards_count;i++)
        {
        
            if(drives[j]+keyboards[i]>=current)
            {
                set_max=drives[j]+keyboards[i];
              if(set_max<=b)
              {
                  current = set_max;
              }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return current;
}
```